# I found a bug about date

Tags: date, gnu

I am testing the date utility, and have found some unexpected behaviour. My test is to set the date to a given day/month/year, add 24 hours to it, and confirm that it returns the following date.

In my tests below, this works for November 4, 2017, and November 6, 2017, but not for November 5, 2017.

This is clearly a bug, isn't it? How could there be such a fundamental flaw in a key GNU utility?

```
[pp_dt_risk_batch@lvsdmetl05 creditsafe]$ date=`date -d "2017-11-04" +%s`
[pp_dt_risk_batch@lvsdmetl05 creditsafe]$ date_new=`expr $date + 86400`
[pp_dt_risk_batch@lvsdmetl05 creditsafe]$ req_t=`date -d @$date_new "+%Y%m%d"`
[pp_dt_risk_batch@lvsdmetl05 creditsafe]$ echo $req_t
20171105
[pp_dt_risk_batch@lvsdmetl05 creditsafe]$ date=`date -d "2017-11-06" +%s`
[pp_dt_risk_batch@lvsdmetl05 creditsafe]$ date_new=`expr $date + 86400`
[pp_dt_risk_batch@lvsdmetl05 creditsafe]$ req_t=`date -d @$date_new "+%Y%m%d"`
[pp_dt_risk_batch@lvsdmetl05 creditsafe]$ echo $req_t
20171107
[pp_dt_risk_batch@lvsdmetl05 creditsafe]$ date=`date -d "2017-11-05" +%s`
[pp_dt_risk_batch@lvsdmetl05 creditsafe]$ date_new=`expr $date + 86400`
[pp_dt_risk_batch@lvsdmetl05 creditsafe]$ req_t=`date -d @$date_new "+%Y%m%d"`
[pp_dt_risk_batch@lvsdmetl05 creditsafe]$ echo $req_t
20171105

[pp_dt_risk_batch@lvsdmetl05 creditsafe]$ date --version
date (GNU coreutils) 8.4
Copyright (C) 2010 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by David MacKenzie.
```

Comment: What bug? You should explain what you expected and what you got instead. I don't think users should have to pick through this and infer what those are when you could simply point them out.

Comment: Not a bug. DST time ended on Nov. 5, 2017 in most of North America, so the day was 25 hours long.

Comment: Great catch, seems worth an answer to me (there are near-dupes, but maybe not considered specific enough to flag).

Comment: It didn't seem like a great question, so I was reluctant to provide an answer in its current form. But - if a bad question leads to a good answer, I guess it's worth a try.

Comment: Ah, yes, assuming that a day has 86400 seconds. If only!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears you are concerned with the apparent discrepancy suggested by the following (noting that 86400 seconds = 24 hours)

- 2017-11-04 00:00 + 86400 seconds = 2017-11-05 00:00
- 2017-11-05 00:00 + 86400 seconds = 2017-11-05 24:00 (see below!)
- 2017-11-06 00:00 + 86400 seconds = 2017-11-07 00:00

This is *not* a bug.

You don't mention what timezone you are in, but in most of North America, 2017-11-05 was the day on which Daylight Saving Time ended, so it was 25 hours long (90000 seconds).

Comment: Great, thanks for the editing! I am posting my first question at stackoverflow, I am not familiar with format, I tried to reformat the question, but found it was formatted nicely by someone else, that's magic

Comment: @ElvinLin, NP. If you think my answer is correct, you can accept it (click on the grey checkmark) and upvote it. Also recommend you [take the tour](https://stackexchange.com/tour).

Comment: Haha that is about the longest I have ever had to wait for an accepted answer - 16 months! Thanks for coming back to this question!